# isnull(col1,col2) equivalent in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

How can I write an equivalent statement to the below SQL query?

```
SELECT ISNULL(df2.id, df1.id) as new_id
FROM dataframe1 df1
    LEFT JOIN dataframe2 df2
    ON df1.id = df2.id
```

Comment: I'm possibly misunderstanding, but doesn't this just reduce to `SELECT id from dataframe1`?    The literal translation would be something like `df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left'); df['id'].fillna(df['id'])`

Comment: @chrisb The `LEFT JOIN` has `df1` on the left.  That means `df2`, on the right may have `NULL` values for `df2.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such equivalent would be:

```
df2.set_index('id').combine_first(df1.set_index('id')).reset_index()
```